# Select rows where value is equal given value or lower and nearest to it

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

Sorry for confusing title. Please, tell, if it's possible to do via db request. Assume we have following table

```
   ind_id      name                 value       date
----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------
1           a                    10          2010-01-01
1           a                    20          2010-01-02
1           a                    30          2010-01-03
2           b                    10          2010-01-01
2           b                    20          2010-01-02
2           b                    30          2010-01-03
2           b                    40          2010-01-04
3           c                    10          2010-01-01
3           c                    20          2010-01-02
3           c                    30          2010-01-03
3           c                    40          2010-01-04
3           c                    50          2010-01-05
4           d                    10          2010-01-05
```

I need to query all rows to include each `ind_id` once for the given date, and if there's no `ind_id` for given date, then take the nearest lower date, if there's no any lower dates, then return ind_id + name (name/ind_id pairs are equal) with nulls.
For example, date is 2010-01-04, I expect following result:

```
ind_id      name                 value       date
----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------
1           a                    30          2010-01-03
2           b                    40          2010-01-04
3           c                    40          2010-01-04
4           d                    NULL        NULL
```

If it's possible, I'll be very grateful if someone help me with building query. I'm using SQL server 2008.

Comment: "name/ind_id pairs are equal" - does this mean that for a given id, the name will always be the same? If so, it represents denormalisation in the DB schema, unless the underlying data is coming from multiple tables - does the data shown come from a single table, or from multiple tables?

Comment: @Mark Bannister Yeah, I know that, this table is a result of another request :)

Comment: OK, so it is from a single table - thanks.

Comment: Thank you, guys! If I could accept all the answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this **[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da4ed/2)**

```
with CTE_test
as 
(
    select int_id,
       max(date) MaxDate
    from test 
    where date<='2010-01-04 00:00:00:000'
    group by int_id
)
select A.int_id, A.[Value], A.[Date]
from test A
    inner join CTE_test B
       on a.int_id=b.int_id 
          and a.date = b.Maxdate
union all
select int_id, null, null 
from test 
where int_id not in (select int_id from CTE_test)
```

Comment: Appreciate for deep insight, yes, the previous answer was wrong. Timofei didn't ask for max(value). I udpate the answer and corresponding demo.

Answer (score 2):

(Updated) Try:

```
with cte as
(select m.*,
        max(date) over (partition by ind_id) max_date,
        max(case when date <= @date then date end) over 
           (partition by ind_id) max_acc_date
 from myTable m)
select ind_id,
       name,
       case when max_acc_date is null then null else value end value, 
       max_acc_date date
from cte c
where date = coalesce(max_acc_date, max_date)
```

(SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef7aa/1))

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
declare @date date = '2010-01-04'

;with ids as
(
  select distinct ind_id
  from myTable
)
,ranks as
(
  select *
    , ranking = row_number() over (partition by ind_id order by date desc)
  from myTable
  where date <= @date
)
select ids.ind_id
  , ranks.value
  , ranks.date
from ids
  left join ranks on ids.ind_id = ranks.ind_id and ranks.ranking = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71e6e/15).

Ideally you wouldn't be using the `DISTINCT` statement to get the `ind_id` values to include, but I've used it in this case to get the results you needed.

Also, standard disclaimer for these sorts of queries; if you have duplicate data you should consider a tie-breaker column in the `ORDER BY` or using `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

**Edited after OPs update**

Just add the new column into the existing query:

```
with ids as
(
  select distinct ind_id, name
  from myTable
)
,ranks as
(
  select *
    , ranking = row_number() over (partition by ind_id order by date desc)
  from myTable
  where date <= @date
)
select ids.ind_id
  , ids.name
  , ranks.value
  , ranks.date
from ids
  left join ranks on ids.ind_id = ranks.ind_id and ranks.ranking = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75b95/3).

As with the previous one it would be best to get the `ind_id`/`name` information through joining to a standing data table if available.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that returns the result that you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    t1.ind_id
,   CASE WHEN t1.date <= '2010-01-04' THEN t1.value ELSE null END
FROM test t1
WHERE t1.date=COALESCE(
    (SELECT MAX(DATE)
    FROM test t2
    WHERE t2.ind_id=t1.ind_id AND t2.date <= '2010-01-04')
,   t1.date)
```

The idea is to pick a row in a correlated query such that its ID matches that of the current row, and the date is the highest one prior to your target date of `'2010-01-04'`.

When such row does not exist, the date for the current row is returned. This date needs to be replaced with a `null`; this is what the `CASE` statement at the top is doing.

Here is a [demo on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/341b4/23).

Answer (score 1):

Use option with [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188336.aspx) operator

```
DECLARE @date date = '20100104'
SELECT ind_id,
       CASE WHEN date <= @date THEN value END AS value,
       CASE WHEN date <= @date THEN date END AS date
FROM dbo.test57 t
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.test57 t2
              WHERE t.ind_id = t2.ind_id AND t2.date <= @date
              HAVING ISNULL(MAX(t2.date), t.date) = t.date
              )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54c0b/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME;

SET @date = '2010-01-04';

WITH temp1 AS
(
SELECT t.ind_id
, t.name
, CASE WHEN t.date <= @date THEN t.value ELSE NULL END AS value
, CASE WHEN t.date <= @date THEN t.date ELSE NULL END AS date
FROM test1 AS t
),

temp AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ind_id ORDER BY t.date DESC) AS rn
FROM temp1 AS t
WHERE t.date <= @date OR t.date IS NULL
)

SELECT *
FROM temp AS t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer but will give you the concept as i just write it down quickly without any testing.

```
use
go 
if
(Select value from table where col=@col1) is not null
--you code to get the match value
else if 
(Select LOWER(Date) from table ) is not null
-- your query to get the nerst dtae record
else
--you query withh null value
end
```